# JS use parseFloat,there are a lot of 0 in the decimal

Tags: javascript

I use this way to divide a decimal.I want to divide this number by 100.

```
var myNumber="1245.6699";
myNumber=""+parseFloat(myNumber)*10000/1000000;//"12.4566990000000002"
myNumber=Number(myNumber);//12.4566990000000002
```

I want this division to keep 6 digit decimal like this `12.456699`,but now the result is `12.4566990000000002`,how to modify?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to deal with floating point number precision in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1458633/how-to-deal-with-floating-point-number-precision-in-javascript)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `toFixed()` method of [Number](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number) object:

```js
var myNumber = "1245.6699";
console.log(
  (myNumber / 100).toFixed(6)
)
```

Comment: Though, this does require knowing in advance where exactly the cutoff between significant and non-significant digits are.

Comment: @CertainPerformance, thanks for your comment, they wrote 6 digits.